# Custom rendering of a StructBlock in Wagtail 2.2

Tags: wagtail

I'm using a simple StructBlock with the following code:

```
from wagtail.core import blocks

class ProfileById(blocks.StructBlock):

  ids = blocks.CharBlock(label='Profile by ID')

  class Meta:
    template = 'myapp/blocks/profile_by_id.html'
    icon = 'user'
```

But when this component gets rendered to a page, it should perform a quick API call to a server using a url like `f'https://api.server.ours/profiles/?ids={ids}&format=json'`, turn that json into something Python can traverse, and then tap into that data in the `myapp/blocks/profile_by_id.html` template.

Is there a def that class that extend from StructBlock can override to "do things" that lets us put additional data into the templating context so that by the time the template gets rendered, that additional data can be tapped into as well?

I tried to find something like this in the wagtail docs, but couldn't see anything, only that for Page extensions you can override the `serve()` def, which is a completely different hierarachy tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block classes define a `get_context` method which can be overridden to insert additional context variables into the template:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.2/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering
(search for `is_happening_today` for relevant example code)